# How is EXP determined?

Tags: theatrhythm-final-fantasy

Today in *Theatrhythm: Final Fantasy*, I decided to take my chances on a set of music with which I was on familiar.

Things were going well. I managed to score an S on the first two songs (EMS and FMS). This got me 300 EXP on one, and 700ish on the second. Upon completion of those two, I went on to do the Battle round. After only scoring an A on this one, I was amazed to see that I got a whopping 2500 EXP! This was enough to level my (fairly low level) party up three times a piece! I have no idea *how* I got 2500 EXP, so:

**How does this game determine just how much EXP you're getting?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a user on gamefaqs answering the question [how the exp calculation works](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/635802-theatrhythm-final-fantasy/63357669):

> The amount of experience is calculated from the difficulty level as well as the number of monsters you kill. Depending on your levels and your groups, you will need to find a good balance, as if you jump into a high level song but can't even kill the first guy you get nothing, and conversely slaying 12 guys in the lowest difficulty is also probably not so great.